# Daughter needs an F1 study visa for a summer drama program US but only has 1 week until flights from the UK

Tags: visas, usa, esta, student-visas

She is 16 and we have just found out that she needs an F1 visa for the summer program and have now urgently applied via the US Emabssy website in the UK.  We have the I-20 and DS-160 completed and she has her UK passport.

When completing the DS-160 we were told that interviews for F1 are currently being waived until the end of 2022.

She is 16 and we are travelling out to drop her off under our ESTAs.

We don't appear to be able to create an emergency appointment or interview and when i phoned we have been told to send in an email (which we did) and wait for a reply.

Problem is, they say it could take 4-5 working days to get a reply but we need to fly out in a week.

Does anyone have any advice for this, please?

Could she travel out on an ESTA for now?
Is there a way of getting an appointment at the US embassy in the next few days?

Having paid a lot for the summer program we are panicing now we have found out that an F1 is technically required.

Please help

Comment: Have you spoken to the people running the summer program?  They probably deal with this all the time and may have some advice for you.

Comment: Call an immigration lawyer IMMIDIATELY. I strongly recommend against "fudging" this. If you make a mistake, your daughter might get barred from the US for a long time.

Comment: Hi, follow up question: why did you think she did not need the F1 if the program she's supposed to attend sent you the I-20? The only purpose of the I-20 is to apply for the F1.

Comment: Thanks all.  The school weren’t very helpful. My daughter received the I-20 but didn’t realise what was required. We got involved too late.

Comment: I’ve reached out to a lawyer hoping they can help somehow. Don’t know how, though.  Does anyone think there is any chance at all that we can get an f-1 in a week?

Comment: in a week? very unlikely. Emergency appointments are for unexpected events like illnesses and deaths, not forgetful daughters... You let your 16-years old plan an international study program all on her own? That's on you, not on the embassy or the daughter, with all due respect.